# How can I force all clients to use Squid Proxy server on hotspot

Tags: networking, iptables, hostapd, ap-hotspot

I have two wifi interfaces, one is inbuilt and another is a USB adapter. As research, I want to use hostapd to start a hotspot and give users IP addresses using dnsmasq. I used nftables following this guide https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Internet_sharing to share internet to the clients.

Here are my Squid config entries

```
http_access deny blockedsites

acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12      # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
include /etc/squid/conf.d/*.conf
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow all
http_port 3128
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern \/(Packages|Sources)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/Release(|\.gpg)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/InRelease$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/(Translation-.*)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
shutdown_lifetime 10 seconds
```

All clients connect to the *wlan1* interface for an internet connection. How can possibly force all client requests to go via the Squid Proxy Server? I am comfortable with using iptables or other similar pacakges

Answer (score 0):

if you are comfortable using iptables you can respond you question yourself.
use DNAT for a simple port as example.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <proxy IP>
```

(needed for all ports)

disclamer:

1. That's what you want to do is a transparent proxy. All traffic must
   pass an (ubuntu-) Server that does the iptables redirect.
2. This works very well for http, but not for https - as you implement some kind of
   man in the middle attack. But this is a different sorry and not part
   of your question :-)